# MySQL: deleting rows based on a condition with data from another table and NO JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a TABLE1 like this:

[image]

And a TABLE2 like this:

[image]

I want to delete entries from table 1 whose endTimestamp is not equal to ANY table 2 entry endTimestamp, with a margin of 1000 time units.

(I know in this example all the entries from table 1 and table 2 have the same timestamp values, so the 5 entries from table 1 should be kept, and any other should be erased if existed)

Since the ids of both tables are not related to each other, I can't perform a JOIN operation as long as I know.

How can I do this?

EDIT: Tried [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/126b6/7). Works, but does not work at my server :|

Comment: "I can't perform a JOIN operation.." - [but you *can* use a JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Comment: (In SQL *any* field in the joined tables can be used to establish a relationship - doesn't matter if they are 'ids' or bound with FK/relational constraints.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for :

```
delete from table1 where endTimestamp not in (Select endTimestamp from table2)
```

Edit : As pointed out by @user2864740, you can very well use Join here too, even if the ids of both tables are not related to each other.

```
DELETE FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.endTimestamp = table2.endTimestamp;
```

Comment: The OP doesn't believe he/she can use a JOIN with a DELETE .. which is incorrect. I almost always recommend JOIN-syntax over sub-selects which *are* a kind of join anyway.

Comment: He assumes that having dissimilar id's prevents him from using Join. Agreed that Joins are always recommended.

Comment: Is this solution compatible with using a margin for the endTimestamp comparison? Or is that the way of using the JOIN and allows only equal values?

Comment: For both In Clause and Joins, You always deal with exact value comparisons.

Comment: I'm trying with a select for testing: SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS t2 ON (t2.EndTimestamp - t1.EndTimestamp <= 900); It returns 0 entries. What's wrong?

Comment: @ManishKr.Shukla The select does work, my mistake. But the delete query as tou wrote it gives me syntax error, "INNER" is marked into mysql-workbench so I guess that's where the problem is. On sqlFiddle I cannot perform deletes so I can't test. Any idea?